# Embedded ARM/Raspberry Pi Assembly in C

Tags: c, assembly, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am porting a library from Arduino to Raspbian.  There is a section of embedded assembly that I cannot quite figure out and I am hoping someone can help or perhaps point me to a different resource.  Helpfully, the code is well commented, so fingers crossed. Many thanks in advance.

The Arduino code is:

```
// The macro below uses 3 instructions per pin to generate the byte to transfer with SPI
// Retreive duty cycle setting from memory (ldd, 2 clockcycles)
// Compare with the counter (cp, 1 clockcycle) --> result is stored in carry
// Use the rotate over carry right to shift the compare result into the byte. (1 clockcycle).
#define add_one_pin_to_byte(sendbyte, counter, ledPtr) \
{ \
    unsigned char pwmval=*ledPtr; \
    asm volatile ("cp %0, %1" : /* No outputs */ : "r" (counter), "r" (pwmval): ); \
    asm volatile ("ror %0" : "+r" (sendbyte) : "r" (sendbyte) : );  \
}

unsigned char sendbyte;
add_one_pin_to_byte(sendbyte, counter, --ledPtr);
```

I believe that on ARM/Raspberry Pi "compare" is "CMP" rather than "CP", but the problem is with the "ROR" statement.  I get an error message at build that says:

```
/tmp/ccZN1jmK.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccZN1jmK.s:138: Error: bad arguments to instruction -- `ror r3'
```

I understand that "ROR" is Rotate Over Right, and I expect the compiler put the "r3" in, and that "r3" is probably the fourth register (third register if you use zeroth I suppose).

While this code is designed to be very tight, allowing a low power processor to do a lot of work, I would be OK converting it to C and eliminating the assembly if necessary.

Comment: From a quick glance something like `sendbyte = (sendbyte >> 1) | (counter == *ledPtr) ? 0x80 : 0x00;`

Comment: can't see the assembly code but I think you can only do ROR on accumulator register, so move R3 to A and try again?

Comment: By the way, even the original code is broken/unsafe. There is no guarantee that the carry flag will be preserved between the two asm blocks. It should have been written as one block.

Answer (score 4):

> I am porting a library from Arduino to Raspbian.

This isn't going to work.

[The library you're trying to port](https://github.com/elcojacobs/ShiftPWM) is designed very specifically for the hardware of the AVR microcontroller used on the Arduino. It depends on the availability of memory-mapped port I/O and uses specific hardware timers.

The Raspberry Pi is a completely different system. Many of the features that this library depends upon are unavailable on the BCM283x processor used on the Pi. Moreover, the BCM283x runs at a much higher clock speed, making most of the optimizations used by this library unnecessary (and even inappropriate).

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here exactly, but you will need to approach this at a higher level. Trying to perform a line-by-line "translation" of this code isn't going to yield useful results.

Comment: While I appreciate the feedback, "this isn't going to work" is neither helpful nor accurate.  I understand the architectural and functional differences between the two platforms.  Keep it positive.

Comment: There's a limit to how much I can sugar-coat an answer! If you are aware of the differences, then: how do you plan on replacing this library's use of timer interrupts?

Comment: setitimer(ITMER_REAL, ...) gives me an analog of interrupts on SIGALRM.

Answer (score -4):

My problem was that on ARM/Raspberry Pi, the ROR instruction wants two parameters, destination register and register to be rotated.  On the Arduino, the processor only required a single parameter.  The statement that will build is:

```
asm volatile ("ROR %0, %1" : "=r" (sendbyte) : "r" (sendbyte) : );
```

However, I have decided to use something close to @Jester's C code.

Comment: **You're now using `sendbyte` as the rotate count, as well as the value to be rotated.**  See [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](//stackoverflow.com/q/776508)   use an intrinsic or pure C (because compilers know how to optimize to a rotate instruction); especially useful for ARM where a `ROR` can be applied to an operand for an instruction other than `mov`.  (The `ror` mnemonic is just an alias for `mov dst, src ror count`.  **But also note that AVR ROR rotates through carry; that's why it's doing a compare first.**  The comments in the source even explain that.